# Is it possible to add HTML (such as an img tag) to link_to helper in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I see it being escaped, and in this case want to avoid that for a certain link. Or is the only way to build the link with HTML and ERB?

```
link_to("#{image_tag(@image.image.mini.url)} Next", @image.next_image, :class => "scroll next") if @image.next_image
```

EDIT: realising it may be my string-building that causes the problem, added my code to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.html_safe`.

```
link_to("#{image_tag(@image.image.mini.url)} Next".html_safe, @image.next_image, :class => "scroll next") if @image.next_image
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
= link_to @image.next_image do
   <span> hey ya'll i'm some html! </span>
```